# Wordpress SQL Query on new table

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I've created a new table in the wordpress database.

I have then created template and I am adding custome php code in there but wrapped in wordpress header and footer.

My question is, how can I query my new table, as wordpress already does the database connection etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the WordPress documentation there is a section "[Run any Query on the Database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database)" that suggest to use:

```
<?php $wpdb->query('query'); ?>
```

Where `query` is your SQL query you want to execute.

Please be sure to [protect your queries against SQL injection](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to avoid these kind of things:

[image]

Comment: <?php $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('query')); ?> takes care of escaping SQL to protect against injection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [$wpdb class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).